# Is there any kind of 'point' of 'target' in order to center things shown in the camera view?

Tags: interface, camera

Is there any kind of 'point' of 'target' in order to center things shown in the camera view, like adding a little box in the middle of the view so i can adjust the scene?

Comment: Please clarify the question further, it's not very clear what you're asking.

Comment: you can enable thirds division veiw.

Comment: You want a marker to show where the center of the camera is? Or do you want to center the camera on an object? Or..?

Comment: To center the camera on an object, you could use the track to constraint either using the object as the target, or an empty as a target (this allows a bit more freedom). Is that what you where looking for? If so, I'll write up an answer.

Comment: This is a bit more of a hack, but if you want to see the center point of the camera, you could enable limits, and then you can see the center of where the camera is looking in the viewport (but not from the camera view)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can enable the *center* guide in the *Properties > camera settings > Composition Guides*:

[image]

You might also want to look at *[safe areas](http://blender.org/manual/render/camera/safe_areas.html)*:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add a track to constraint to the camera. This will control where the camera is looking.

To add one, select the camera, and then the object you want to be the target (I recommend an empty), and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.

Your cameras rotation should then snap to the empty.